# Cross verifying sums in 12 different views

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to create a control that verifies that the sum of a number between 12 different views, within three companies in each view is the same.

From time to time, something goes wrong and there's a small difference in the sums in two or more of the views in one or two of the companies.

Right now, I'm working on a SQL that gets very very long, since I'm calculating the sum of table A, and joining the sum from table B and selecting those companies where there's a difference. Then I'm making a UNION ALL from a new SQL where I'm comparing the sum in table A with the sum in table C. Since I have 12 different views that all has to be compared to each other, the SQL just get so long and the risk of an error increases.

Is there a smart and nicer way to go about this, where I don't have to manually cross-compare all 12 view with other in all possible combinations?

Certainly. When I'm talking about difference I'm not talking about small differences in the third decimal. This could be thousands or even a couple of millions because someone made a transaction error in the main-program that feeds into the tables.

In the code below I'm comparing the sums in TableA to the sums in TableB and TableC. If I manually have to add all the possible comparisons between the 12 different view, the code will end up being VERY long and I'd like to avoid that if possible.

```
> SELECT  a.Companyid ,
>         ( a.[View] + ' vs. ' + b.[View] ) AS Views ,
>         ( a.[Mv.Facts.TableA] - b.[Mv.Facts.TableB] ) AS Difference FROM    ( SELECT    Companyid ,
>                     'Facts.TableA' AS [View] ,
>                     SUM(MV) AS [Mv.Facts.TableA]
>           FROM      TABLE a
>           WHERE     Companyid IN ( 3, 5, 36 )
>           GROUP BY  Companyid ,
>         ) a
>         LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT    Companyid ,
>                                     'Facts.TableB' AS [View] ,
>                                     SUM(Mv) AS [Mv.Facts.TableB]
>                           FROM      TABLE B
>                           WHERE     Companyid IN ( 3, 5, 36 )
>                           GROUP BY  Companyid) b ON a.Companyid = b.Companyid WHERE   ROUND(( a.[Mv.Facts.TableA] - b.[Mv.Facts.TableB]
> ), 0) <> 0
> 
> 
> UNION ALL SELECT  Companyid ,
>         ( a.[View] + ' vs. ' + c.[View] ) AS Views ,
>         ( a.[Mv.Facts.TableA] - c.[Mv.Facts.TableC] ) AS Difference FROM    ( SELECT    Companyid ,
>                     'Facts.TableA' AS [View] ,
>                     SUM(Mv) AS [Mv.Facts.TableA]
>           FROM      TABLE a
>           WHERE     Companyid IN ( 3, 5, 36 )
>           GROUP BY  Companyid ) a LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT             Companyid ,
>                     'Facts.TableC' AS [View] ,
>                     SUM(Mv) AS [Mv.Facts.TableC]
>           FROM      TABLE C
>           WHERE     Companyid IN ( 3, 5, 36 )
>           GROUP BY  Companyid) c ON a.Companyid = c.Companyid WHERE ROUND((a.[Mv.Facts.TableA] - c.[Mv.Facts.TableC]),0) <> 0
```

Comment: You should post some code and some detailed example with sample data. Otherwise you have a high chance of having this question closed.

Comment: Can you show some code here?  Floating point arithmetic is not always exact.

Comment: Code added to original post. When I'm talking about differences I'm not talking about small differences in the third decimal. This could be thousands or even a couple of millions because someone made a transaction error in the main-program that feeds into the tables.